# Smartly encrypting strings

Tags: c#, caesar-cipher

I am trying to encrypt the input string using the following rule:

- 1st Character of string will be increment by 4 ( a will become e )
- 2nd Character of string will be increment by 1 ( a will become b )
- 3rd Character of string will be increment by 7 ( a will become h )
- Rest of the characters will be replaced using the above rules.

**Examples:**

```
(Before Enc)    (After Enc)
""              ""         
"b"             "f"       
"x"             "b"     
"imagine"       "mnhkjui"
"abcdef"        "ecjhfm"
"xz"            "ba"
```

I have written the following code to achieve this:

```
public static string Puzzle(string str) 
{
    string result = "";
    var w = s.a;
    string x = "";
    foreach (var item in str)
    {
        if (item + (int)w > 122)
        {
            x += (char)(96 + ((item + (int)w) % 122));
        }
        else
        {
            x += (char)((int)w + item);
        }
        w = Convert(w);
    }
    return x;
}

enum s { a = 4, b = 1, c = 7 };

private static s Convert(s w)
{
    if (w == s.a)
    {
        w = s.b;
    }
    else if (w == s.b)
    {
        w = s.c;
    }
    else
    {
        w = s.a;
    }
    return w;
}
```

What I want is a better and more efficient solution than the one I have written.

Comment: More efficient in what sense?

Comment: more efficient in smart code, faster and just better than this...

Comment: Can you post code that compiles first? Where is `x` declared?

Comment: I posted code that is working fine,I just need to make it smarter...

Comment: Your code does not compile. Like I said, where is `x` declared? What is it supposed to be? Should `x` be `result`?

Comment: You edited your comment, and sorry I must have deleted the line copying or formatting the code, any ways I have edited the post.

Comment: Just so it's said:  this isn't encryption.  Encryption requires a key.  At best, this is encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Convert` function cycles through the values `4, 1, 7`. You do this by comparing the given state with each possible state, and then return the next state. This could be made much simpler by using an index rather than values. Then instead of calling `Convert`, we can increment the index and if necessary wrap the index around by using a modulo operation. When we need the value, we can use the index to look it up in an array that contains these values.

This would look similar to:

```csharp
int[] states = {4, 1, 7};
int i = 0;

// get the value:
states[i]

// increment the index:
i = (i + 1) % states.Length;
```

If we really want to go overboard with this, we could define a type that represents these cyclical states:

```csharp
class Cycle<T>
{
    private readonly T[] values;
    private int i = 0;

    public Cycle(params T[] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return values[i];
        }

    }

    public static Cycle<T> operator++ (Cycle<T> cycle)
    {
        cycle.i = (cycle.i + 1) % cycle.values.Length;
        return cycle;
    }
}
```

Used as:

```csharp
var states = new Cycle<int>(4, 1, 7);

// get the value:
states.Value

// increment the index:
++states;
```

While using such a class makes for a very nice interface, it's not exactly the most efficient thing to do. Using an array as shown at the top is probably a good compromise between good code and performance. In particular, both of my solutions allow you to set the values of the cycle at runtime, rather than hardcoding all values in an `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the comments in [amon's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/77917/17000) I'd suggest you to change the following things:

- change the type of `result` to [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `string`. It is more efficient.
- try to use meaningful names. I think it would be clearer if you would call your variables in a different way. For instance, I'd use `offset` in place of `w`. Wouldn't it be clearer?

Looking at the code, I'd introduce some functions to make it clearer. Using `Cycle` as described in amon's answer it's great. I'd also factor out the code to compute the encrypted value.

```
var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var offsets = new Cycle<int>(4, 1, 7);
foreach (var currentCharacter in inputString)
{
    outputBuilder.Append(Encrypt(currentCharacter, offsets.Value);
    ++offsets;
}
return outputBuilder.ToString();
```